# Do parenthesized groups work in Scala?

Tags: regex, scala

Parentheses in regular expressions don't seem to work in match/case statements. For example, the following code

```
val pat1 = """ab""".r
val pat2 = """(a)(b)""".r
val pat3 = """((a)(b))""".r
val pat4 = """((a)b)""".r
val pat5 = """(ab)""".r
"ab" match {
  case pat1(x) => println("1 " + x)
  case pat2(x) => println("2 " + x)
  case pat3(x) => println("3 " + x)
  case pat4(x) => println("4 " + x)
  case pat5(x) => println("5 " + x)
  case _ => println("None of the above")
}
```

prints  "5 ab", but I would have expected any of the patterns to match. I'd like to use "(...)?" optional elements, but I can't. Related to this, I can't get (?m) to work. My patterns work okay outside of a match/case expression. Can someone explain to me how Scala handles regular expressions in match/case expressions?

I'm trying to write a tokenizer in Scala

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Regex` defines `unapplySeq`, not `unapply`, which means that you get each group in its own variable.  Also, although lower-case matchers may work in some instances (i.e. with parameters), you really should use upper-case.  So, what will work is:

```
val Pat1 = """ab""".r
val Pat2 = """(a)(b)""".r
val Pat3 = """((a)(b))""".r
val Pat4 = """((a)b)""".r
val Pat5 = """(ab)""".r
def no() { println("No match") }
"ab" match { case Pat1() => println("Pat1"); case _ => no }
"ab" match { case Pat2(x,y) => println("Pat2 "+x+" "+y); case _ => no }
"ab" match { case Pat3(x,y,z) => println("Pat3 "+x+" "+y+" "+z); case _ => no }
"ab" match { case Pat4(x,y) => println("Pat4 "+x+" "+y); case _ => no }
"ab" match { case Pat5(x) => println("Pat5 "+x); case _ => no }
```

(You will always get a match.)

If you want all matches, use `@ _*`

```
"ab" match { case Pat3(w @ _*) => println(w); case _ => no }
```

I'm not sure what you mean by `(?a)` so I don't know what's wrong with it.  Don't confuse `(?a)` with `(?:a)` (or with `(a?)` or with `(a)?`).

Comment: Great, thanks! I tried a lot of things, but not more than one parameter to the pattern.

The other part I wondered about was that I was trying to use the m flag to make '.' accept newlines (like i for case-insensitive), and somewhere it said to use the form (?m). How would you do either of these?

Comment: `.` accepting newlines is DOTALL mode, which is `(?s)`.  Multiline mode (`(?m)`) governs `^` and `$` behavior.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can access `group(1)` of each match:

```
val string = "one493two483three"
val pattern = """two(\d+)three""".r
pattern.findAllIn(string).matchData foreach {
  m => println(m.group(1))
}
```

Test this demo **[here](http://ideone.com/2XVzay)**.